# .htaccess rewrite to short url handle exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about$ about.php       
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^user/([^/.]+)?$ user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

What I am trying to do is when someone goes to mysite.com/username
it will do : user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
which is simply : `RewriteRule ^/([^/.]+)?$ user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`

but what if the username is a page name?
for example if the username is about, or contact ? is there a way to add exceptions ? or how do I go about handling that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a blacklist of usernames. Don't allow somebody to create a username that matches a required page on your site. If you put the [L] flag on your current rules, it will stop further rules processing, so you can just add another rule at the bottom to catch the usernames.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?$ user.php?uname=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Of course even if you don't blacklist the usernames the system should work. They will just have to use /user/about, as the /about URI would already be used.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using L (last flag) and that can fix your problem. Use this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about.php [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?uname=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirection for example

```
Redirect /about http://mysite.com/about.php
```

Hope this helps.